# Count only unique strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, spreadsheet

I have a column with strings. I only want to count the strings which are unique.

I know that I could just derive all distinct strings(by pasting them) and then count them with `=Count(...)`. However I do not want to destroy my dataset. Therefore, is there a formula for counting only unique strings?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)=1))
```

In picture below unique values highlighted with blue:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer! Why are you taking `1* ` in your formula?

Comment: it's a special trick: `COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)=1` returns `true/false` array: `{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FAlSE,...}` (sumproduct can't sum this array) and `1*{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FAlSE,...}` converts this array to number array: `{0,0,1,0,...}`. Alternatively you could use 1) `=SUMPRODUCT(0+(COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)=1))` 2) `=SUMPRODUCT(--(COUNTIF(A1:A10,A1:A10)=1))`